# quickly-ubuntu template showing unmet dependencies and broken packages

Tags: installation, quickly

I tried to install `quickly-ubuntu-template` using:

```
sudo apt-get install quickly-ubuntu-template
```

This is what it returned:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 quickly-ubuntu-template : Depends: python-pygame but it is not going to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

Help please ?

Comment: Oh same thing happend to me too ,waiting for the solution :)

Answer (score 1):

`sudo apt-get install quickly-ubuntu-template python-pygame`

I'm not extremely familiar with the inner workings of dpkg, but I find it odd that it didn't automatically pull in python-pygame.